# Docker container running apache always exposing port 80

Tags: apache, docker, port

I have a Docker image that runs Apache, and I have configured Apache (through **httpd.conf**) to listen on port `8080`.

```
Listen 8080
```

When I build my image and run it, I'm able to successfully connect to my website via port `8080`, so all seems well at this point.

```
docker build -t my/apache:8080 .
docker run --name "MyWebsite" -p 8080:8080 -v ~/dir:/mnt/dir -d -t my/apache:8080
```

However, when I list my running containers using `docker ps`, I see that port `80` has also been exposed for some reason.

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                            NAMES
23c4e1f0ea66        my/apache:8080      "/docker-entrypoint.…"   12 minutes ago      Up 12 minutes       80/tcp, 0.0.0.0:8080->8080/tcp   MyWebsite
```

When I shell on to the running container and search for instances of "Listen 80", nothing shows up other than the instance of "Listen 8080" that I added to **httpd.conf**.

```
docker exec -it 23c4e1f0ea66 /bin/bash
grep -ri "Listen 80"
```

My Dockerfile contains only one `EXPOSE` declaration - `EXPOSE 8080`. However, I don't believe this actually exposes the port anyway, and is intended more as a way of documenting which port should be exposed when running a container that utilizes the image.

How can I find out when is exposing port `80`, and crucially, how can I stop it from being exposed?

## Dockerfile

```
FROM httpd:2.4

COPY httpd.conf /usr/local/apache2/conf/
COPY docker-entrypoint.sh /

ENTRYPOINT ["/docker-entrypoint.sh"]
CMD ["apache"]

### Apache (proxies to MapProxy).
EXPOSE 8080
```

## Entrypoint script

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e

if [ "$1" = 'apache' ]; then
        echo "Starting Apache"
        httpd-foreground
fi

exec "$@"
```

## HTTP config

```
ServerRoot "/usr/local/apache2"

Listen 8080

LoadModule mpm_event_module modules/mod_mpm_event.so
LoadModule authn_file_module modules/mod_authn_file.so
LoadModule authn_core_module modules/mod_authn_core.so
LoadModule authz_host_module modules/mod_authz_host.so
LoadModule authz_groupfile_module modules/mod_authz_groupfile.so
LoadModule authz_user_module modules/mod_authz_user.so
LoadModule authz_core_module modules/mod_authz_core.so
LoadModule access_compat_module modules/mod_access_compat.so
LoadModule auth_basic_module modules/mod_auth_basic.so
LoadModule reqtimeout_module modules/mod_reqtimeout.so
LoadModule filter_module modules/mod_filter.so
LoadModule mime_module modules/mod_mime.so
LoadModule log_config_module modules/mod_log_config.so
LoadModule env_module modules/mod_env.so
LoadModule headers_module modules/mod_headers.so
LoadModule setenvif_module modules/mod_setenvif.so
LoadModule version_module modules/mod_version.so
LoadModule proxy_module modules/mod_proxy.so
LoadModule proxy_http_module modules/mod_proxy_http.so
LoadModule unixd_module modules/mod_unixd.so
LoadModule status_module modules/mod_status.so
LoadModule autoindex_module modules/mod_autoindex.so
<IfModule !mpm_prefork_module>
</IfModule>
<IfModule mpm_prefork_module>
</IfModule>
LoadModule dir_module modules/mod_dir.so
LoadModule alias_module modules/mod_alias.so

<IfModule unixd_module>
        User daemon
        Group daemon
</IfModule>

ServerAdmin applicationdelivery@landmark.co.uk
ServerName mapproxy.gcs.lmkcloud.net:8080
DocumentRoot "/usr/local/apache2/htdocs"
ErrorLog /proc/self/fd/2

LogLevel warn

<IfModule log_config_module>
        LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined
        LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b" common

        <IfModule logio_module>
                LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\" %I %O" combinedio
        </IfModule>

        CustomLog /proc/self/fd/1 common

</IfModule>

<IfModule mime_module>
        TypesConfig conf/mime.types
        AddType application/x-compress .Z
        AddType application/x-gzip .gz .tgz
</IfModule>

<IfModule ssl_module>
        SSLRandomSeed startup builtin
        SSLRandomSeed connect builtin
</IfModule>

ProxyPreserveHost On
ProxyPass / http://example.com:8001/ retry=1 acquire=3000 timeout=20 Keepalive=On
ProxyPassReverse / http://example.com:8001/
```

Comment: Can you please add the Dockerfile?

Comment: @vivekyad4v - Sure, I've added it, along with my entrypoint script. As you can see, it's pretty basic right now, but I plan to add to it going forward.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Port 80 is exposed by the parent Dockerfile for `httpd:2.4` image -
https://github.com/docker-library/httpd/blob/75e85910d1d9954ea0709960c61517376fc9b254/2.4/Dockerfile

A `EXPOSE` statement inside Dockerfile is going to give you an output eventually in `docker ps`. However, that's exposed only to the container network & will not allow communication via the defined ports to containers outside of the same network or to the host machine. To allow this to happen you need to publish the ports.

---

Example -

`docker run -dit --expose 8008 httpd:2.4`

Output -

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                     COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS                  PORTS                              NAMES
d628b537aded        httpd:2.4                 "httpd-foreground"       3 seconds ago       Up 2 seconds            80/tcp, 8008/tcp                   objective_dewdney
```

This exposes the container port. Argument `--expose` is equal to a statement using `EXPOSE`in Dockerfile.

---

Let's try to publish the port now -

`docker run -dit -p 8009 httpd:2.4`

Output -

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                     COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS                  PORTS                              NAMES
2c8c93a78e97        httpd:2.4                 "httpd-foreground"       2 seconds ago       Up 2 seconds            80/tcp, 0.0.0.0:32768->8009/tcp    keen_swirles
```

See the `0.0.0.0:32768`, it's now published to the host machine with a random ephemeral port i.e 32768. You can publish it on a specific host port as well.

---

Example -

`docker run -dit -p 8009:8009 httpd:2.4`

Output -

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                     COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS                  PORTS                              NAMES
1023df9822e5        httpd:2.4                 "httpd-foreground"       2 seconds ago       Up 2 seconds            80/tcp, 0.0.0.0:8009->8009/tcp     fervent_almeida
```

---

In a nutshell, there is no way right now to unexpose the port 80 from parent Dockerfile. You can certainly expose more ports.

It's an open issue -
https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/2210
https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/3465

Adding @BMitch comment to the answer which I believe is spot on since containers can communicate with each other in the same network irrespective of port exposed -

As per @BMitch -

> EXPOSE is only documentation/metadata. It doesn't change how
>   containers communicate with each other. docker ps is just letting you
>   know a port the image creator documented could be published but hasn't
>   been (since there's no host side of the map). There's nothing to
>   change here unless you have code or users that insist this
>   documentation matches your environment. For that, you'd have to
>   rebuild the upstream image.

Comment: So to check my understanding - you are saying that in Docker-world, 'exposing' and 'publishing' a port are considered as two different things? And even though I've not explicitly published a port (using either `-p 8080:8080` or `-P`), a port may still be exposed, even though it wouldn't be listening and as such would be unusable?

Comment: Exactly. Expose is native to the container, publish is for the outside world.

Comment: Well that's a massive issue for me. I can't rip the Dockerfile for `httpd:2.4` and add it to my own because our corporate firewall is blocking some of the commands. And I can't use `Listen 80` because I'm unable to use the root user (something else that I will add to the Dockerfile requires a specific user). I personally would be happy to leave port 80 exposed, but as I'm using an Azure App Service to serve my application, that's not an issue - because both 80 and 8080 are exposed, the App Service simply publishes the lowest of the two, i.e. port 80 (and it seems there is no way to override).

Comment: `EXPOSE` is only documentation/metadata. It doesn't change how containers communicate with each other. `docker ps` is just letting you know a port the image creator documented could be published but hasn't been (since there's no host side of the map). There's nothing to change here unless you have code or users that insist this documentation matches your environment. For that, you'd have to rebuild the upstream image.

Comment: Yes, exactly. Containers can communicate with each other in the same network irrespective of port exposed. Have added your valuable(as always :-)) comment to the answer.

Comment: Marking as the answer because it does fully explain what's happening. Sadly though, with port 80 exposed in the parent docker image, I'm not going to be able to use Azure Web App's as planned.

Answer (score 4):

There is a hint on how to do this at the [DockerHub page](https://hub.docker.com/_/httpd). An alternative config file must be obtained and added to the container via the Dockerfile.

First get a copy of the config file:

```
docker run --rm httpd:2.4 cat /usr/local/apache2/conf/httpd.conf > my-httpd.conf
```

Then edit the `my-httpd.conf` file and modify the port:

```
Listen 8080
```

Finally add to the Dockerfile the instruction to copy it:

```
COPY ./my-httpd.conf /usr/local/apache2/conf/httpd.conf
```