# How to shut down HTTP on httpd docker image

Tags: docker, https, apache2

I have created a container running apache2 http server, loaded my certificates and `https://mydomain` works, however `http://mydomain` works too, and if I digit on my browser `mydomain` the browser open `http://mydomain`. Is there a way to disable http protocol? I use only `-p 443:443` while starting the container.

This is my Dockerfile

```
ARG version=2.4.48-alpine

FROM httpd:$version

LABEL version=1.0

COPY ./public_html/ /usr/local/apache2/htdocs/

# run web traffic over SSL/HTTPS

COPY ./cert/srv.crt /usr/local/apache2/conf/
COPY ./cert/srv.key /usr/local/apache2/conf/

RUN ["sed", "-i", "-e", "'s/^#\(Include .*httpd-ssl.conf\)/\1/'", "-e", "'s/^#\(LoadModule .*mod_ssl.so\)/\1/'", "-e", "'s/^#\(LoadModule .*mod_socache_shmcb.so\)/\1/'", "conf/httpd.conf"]


EXPOSE 443/tcp
```

and this is the outpuf of `docker ps`:

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                          NAMES
21678d6321e4        webserver           "/bin/sh"           2 hours ago         Up About an hour    80/tcp, 0.0.0.0:443->443/tcp   webserver
```

Comment: Hi, how is your container configured? Could you edit by putting your sample codes? so we can help better

Comment: could you add the output of `docker ps` command? also your dockerfile or docker-compoe files as well if possible

Comment: it seems to be a [known issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55917149/docker-container-running-apache-always-exposing-port-80) for httpd image, though is still shouldnt actually publicly publish it... if you stop the container are `http://mydomain` and `https://mydomain` still available?

Comment: @NoamYizraeli no

Comment: just verifying, none of them correct?

Comment: @NoamYizraeli yap

Comment: you can rebuild the image using the official repo [dockerfile](https://github.com/docker-library/httpd/blob/208fc2ba9a097530bb0b7386b0c2bebacdfb6c5c/2.4/Dockerfile) and use it instead, though this whole thing is a bit sus

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved the issue redirecting `http` to `https` exposing also the `80` port.